# Node Texture Connections

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have no idea how to connect the 9 textures to a flat plane just using nodes.
Confusing, in that not all the names on the textures match the input connections on the BSDF.

### All PNG:

1. image
2. ao
3. height
4. metallic n
5. normal
6. roughness
7. roughness_wet
8. smoothness
9. smoothness_wet

[image]

Comment: This tutorial explains it perfectly, with tons of Shader Editor reference images: https://www.cgbookcase.com/learn/how-to-use-pbr-textures-in-blender/